# Generate a random alphanumeric string in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, random, alphanumeric

I want to call a method, pass it the length and have it generate a random alphanumeric string.

Are there any utility libraries out there that may have a bunch of these types of functions?

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty implementation.  Hasn't been tested.

```
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

-(NSString *) randomStringWithLength: (int) len {

    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: len];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
         [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random_uniform([letters length])]];
    }

    return randomString;
}
```

Comment: genRandStringLength should just return randomString. There's no reason to alloc and init (and not autorelease!) a whole new string.

Comment: Fixed.  Should the return type be NSMutableString?  Or is it fine with NSString?

Comment: This is a useful macro to get a very random number: `#define RKRandom(x) (arc4random() % ((NSUInteger)(x) + 1))`

Comment: Just going to put this out there. There's no reason to use an `NSString` for `letters` when a simple `char` array would work just fine. In fact, using `[letters characterAtIndex:(rand() % [letters length])]` seems to me to be less concise than just `letters[rand() % strlen(letters)]`. The Foundation classes are really helpful, but for the simplest things, they can serve to obfusticate our code rather than enhance it.

Comment: @kevingessner Technically, in general, you should probably return [[randomString copy] autorelease].  This is because you then get an immutable result which cannot be changed deliberately or accidentally by other code.

Comment: @JeremyP - I guess. I'm not that [randomString copy] will return an actually immutable string; that's an implementation detail. Since genRandStringLength is defined to return an NSString, it doesn't matter that it's "actually" an NSMutableString; any code that tries to change it is wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan:  I actually started with exactly what you suggested in fact.  I am trying to learn to do things with the Foundation classes, however, so I rewrote it the other way.  I agree, it might be overkill in this case, but it is an example of how to go about it the "objective-c way".

Comment: @kevingessner -copy returns an immutable object "if the consideration “immutable vs. mutable” applies to the receiving object" - from the documentation of NSCopying.  As regards mutable versus immutable, I agree that, in this case, the difference is marginal, but if other code does accidentally send -appendString to the return result, the resulting invalid selector exception is easier to debug than a mysterious and unexplained change in a string you weren't expecting.

Comment: you might want `%C` instead of `%c`, because `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`

Comment: rand() doesn't provide a very random number. Try changing it to arc4random().

Comment: Using arc4random would generate a biased result when the array length is not a power of two. arc4random_uniform fixes this.

Comment: So, is it an updated answer based on the suggestion in comments?

Comment: It must be `arc4random_uniform([letters length])`.      From the man pages `arc4random(void);` and `arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t upper_bound);`

Comment: oh the compiler would give a warning for losing precision, so better to cast to int `arc4random_uniform((int)[letters length])`

Comment: If you don't want to use a static `NSString*` variable you can replace `alphabet` inside of the for loop with `[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]` and change `[alphabet length]` to `[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] count]`

Comment: re: Daneil Rinser's apt point modulo bias, see http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx for a nice description of the issue

Comment: `% [letters length]` seems unnecessary since `arc4random_uniform([letters length])` does the trick on its own.

Comment: @Savagewood NSCharacterSet does not have a `-count` method bud.

Answer (score 111):

Not exactly what you ask, but still useful:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]
```

Sample output:

```
450FEA63-2286-4B49-8ACC-9822C7D4356B-1376-00000239A4AC4FD5
```

Comment: This is by far the shortest and most straightforward way to address the question.

Comment: Even if it has hyphens in it — if that's not a concern then awesome!

Comment: Best answer by a mile

Comment: Perfect for my need to "generate a random alphanumeric string in cocoa". Not exactly what OP asks only because he adds the requirement to "pass it the length" which YAGNI !

Comment: This is probably ok for most uses but DO NOT USE if you need a random string for security purposes. Unique != Random. The length is constant, the range of characters used is limited (0-9, A-F, - = 17, vs 62 for a-Z. 0-9). This string is unique but predictable.

Answer (score 67):

```
NSString *alphabet  = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789";
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:20];
for (NSUInteger i = 0U; i < 20; i++) {
    u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
    unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
    [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to query the length of `alphabet` each time? It is constant and doesn't depend on the loop.

Comment: Tested by generating 1M passwords of 10 characters each and it works great.

Comment: `NSArray` caches its `length`, shouldn't be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: I agree. It's a simple property access. It's not counting itself every time you ask.

Answer (score 47):

Surely you can make this shorter:

```
+(NSString*)generateRandomString:(int)num {
    NSMutableString* string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        [string appendFormat:@"%C", (unichar)('a' + arc4random_uniform(26))];
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: why the -1? There is nothing wrong with this at all. It's like the smallest most optimized out of all the answers.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this one. It's a nice and concise solution. (I wish SO would enforce a comment on downvotes.)

Comment: Best solution. The only comment, I would make it static method.

Comment: The only downside is that it's not really alphanumeric, but just lowercase letters. ;-)

Comment: I think you need to change the 25 to 26, otherwise you'll never get 'z'.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, that's incorrect. arc4random_uniform is 0 to upperbound in this case 25. Z the 25th, A is zero.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato, 'a' + 0 = 'a'. 'a' + 25 = 'y'. You'll never get z unless you change it to 26. Try it, you'll see.

Comment: @PrimaryFeather funny thing is i came here looking for a random a-z only string generator lol

Answer (score 30):

If you're willing to limit yourself to hex characters only, then the simplest option is to generate a UUID:

```
NSString *uuid = [NSUUID UUID].UUIDString;
```

Example output: `16E3DF0B-87B3-4162-A1A1-E03DB2F59654`.

If you want a smaller random string then you can grab just the first 8 characters.

It's a version 4 UUID which means the first character in the 3rd and 4th group is not random (they will always be `4` and one of `8`, `9`, `A` or `B`).

Every other character in the string is fully random and you can generate millions of UUIDs every second for hundreds of years without much risk of the same UUID being generated twice.

Comment: You can simply use `NSString *uuid = [UUID UUID]`

Comment: @orkoden thanks, my code was from some iOS 5 code. I'll update my answer to use the newer iOS 6/OS X 10.8 API.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert  is it safe to use only first 8 characters without the risk of getting same first 8 characters?

Comment: @VishalSingh yes, it is safe, although obviously the shorter you make it the higher your risk of collisions.

Comment: NSString *uuid = [UUID UUID].UUIDString;

will give you error "Use of undeclared identifier UUID", so just a small change in code use 

NSString *uuid = [NSUUID UUID].UUIDString;

Answer (score 24):

A category version of Jeff B's answer.

NSString+Random.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Random)

+ (NSString *)randomAlphanumericStringWithLength:(NSInteger)length;

@end
```

NSString+Random.m

```
#import "NSString+Random.h"

 @implementation NSString (Random)

+ (NSString *)randomAlphanumericStringWithLength:(NSInteger)length
{ 
    NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        [randomString appendFormat:@"%C", [letters characterAtIndex:arc4random() % [letters length]]];
    }

    return randomString;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is a great example of how to use Categories!

Answer (score 7):

You could also just generate a UUID. While not truly random, they are complex and unique which makes them appear random for most uses. Generate one as a string and then take a range of characters equal to the passed length.

Comment: I would strongly advise against this for anything security related. Pseudo-randomness is one of the biggest vunerabilities hackers use in penetrating systems, because they provide predictability. Use as close to real-random as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Swift

```
func randomStringWithLength(length: Int) -> String {
    let alphabet = "-_1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    let upperBound = UInt32(count(alphabet))
    return String((0..<length).map { _ -> Character in
        return alphabet[advance(alphabet.startIndex, Int(arc4random_uniform(upperBound)))]
    })
}
```

Comment: Short & sweet. Worked for me except when I altered the alphabet, it crashed because the alphabet length is hard-coded. I replaced the 64 with UInt32(count(alphabet))

Comment: OK. I replaced the hardcoded `64` with a computed `upperBound`. I compute `upperBound` outside of the block because I think that performs better.

Comment: Cannot invoke 'count' with an argument list of type '(String)'  handles by using 'alphabet.characters.count'

Comment: return alphabet[alphabet.startIndex.advancedBy(Int(arc4random_uniform(upperBound)))

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different way to tackle it. Instead of using a prepared string of characters, you can cast between integers and characters, and generate a dynamic list of characters to select. It's pretty lean and fast, but has a bit more code.

```
int charNumStart = (int) '0';
int charNumEnd = (int) '9';
int charCapitalStart = (int) 'A';
int charCapitalEnd = (int) 'Z';
int charLowerStart = (int) 'a';
int charLowerEnd = (int) 'z';

int amountOfChars = (charNumEnd - charNumStart) + (charCapitalEnd - charCapitalStart) + (charLowerEnd - charLowerStart); // amount of the characters we want.
int firstGap = charCapitalStart - charNumEnd; // there are gaps of random characters between numbers and uppercase letters, so this allows us to skip those.
int secondGap = charLowerStart - charCapitalEnd; // similar to above, but between uppercase and lowercase letters.

// START generates a log to show us which characters we are considering for our UID.
NSMutableString *chars = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:amountOfChars];
for (int i = charNumStart; i <= charLowerEnd; i++) {
    if ((i >= charNumStart && i <= charNumEnd) || (i >= charCapitalStart && i <= charCapitalEnd) || (i >= charLowerStart && i <= charLowerEnd)) {
        [chars appendFormat:@"\n%c", (char) i];
    }
}
NSLog(@"chars: %@", chars);
// END log

// Generate a uid of 20 characters that chooses from our desired range.
int uidLength = 20;
NSMutableString *uid = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:uidLength];
for (int i = 0; i < uidLength; i++) {
    // Generate a random number within our character range.
    int randomNum = arc4random() % amountOfChars;
    // Add the lowest value number to line this up with a desirable character.
    randomNum += charNumStart;
    // if the number is in the letter range, skip over the characters between the numbers and letters.
    if (randomNum > charNumEnd) {
        randomNum += firstGap;
    }
    // if the number is in the lowercase letter range, skip over the characters between the uppercase and lowercase letters.
    if (randomNum > charCapitalEnd) {
        randomNum += secondGap;
    }
    // append the chosen character.
    [uid appendFormat:@"%c", (char) randomNum];
}
NSLog(@"uid: %@", uid);

// Generate a UID that selects any kind of character, including a lot of punctuation. It's a bit easier to do it this way.
int amountOfAnyCharacters = charLowerEnd - charNumStart; // A new range of characters.
NSMutableString *multiCharUid = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:uidLength];
for (int i = 0; i < uidLength; i++) {
    // Generate a random number within our new character range.
    int randomNum = arc4random() % amountOfAnyCharacters;
    // Add the lowest value number to line this up with our range of characters.
    randomNum += charNumStart;
    // append the chosen character.
    [multiCharUid appendFormat:@"%c", (char) randomNum];
}
NSLog(@"multiCharUid: %@", multiCharUid);
```

When I'm doing random character generation, I prefer to work directly with integers and cast them over, instead of writing out the list of chars that I want to draw from. Declaring the variables at the top makes it more system independent, but this code assumes that numbers will have a lower value than letters, and that uppercase letters will have a lower value than lowercase letters.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution in Swift

```
func generateString(len: Int) -> String {
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    let lettersLength = UInt32(countElements(letters))
    let result = (0..<len).map { _ -> String in
        let idx = Int(arc4random_uniform(lettersLength))
        return String(letters[advance(letters.startIndex, idx)])
    }
    return "".join(result)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modification of a few ideas here, and in done Swift 4.0

```
extension String
{
    subscript (i: Int) -> Character
    {
        return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy:i)]
    }

    static func Random(length:Int=32, alphabet:String="ABCDEF0123456789") -> String
    {
        let upperBound = UInt32(alphabet.count)
        return String((0..<length).map { _ -> Character in
            return alphabet[Int(arc4random_uniform(upperBound))]
        })
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let myHexString = String.Random()
let myLongHexString = String.Random(length:64)
let myLettersString = String.Random(length:32, alphabet:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random unicode string, you can create random bytes and then use the valid ones.

```
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    uint8_t * randomBytes = NULL;
    size_t length = 200; // can of course be variable

    randomBytes = malloc( length * sizeof(uint8_t) );
    memset((void *)randomBytes, 0x0, length);

    sanityCheck = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, length, randomBytes);

    if (sanityCheck != noErr) NSLog(@"Error generating random bytes, OSStatus == %ld.", sanityCheck);

    NSData* randomData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)randomBytes length: length];
    if (randomBytes) free(randomBytes);

    NSString* dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:[randomData bytes] length:[randomData length]];  // create an NSString from the random bytes
    NSData* tempData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];             // remove illegal characters from string
    NSString* randomString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tempData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The conversion from NSString to NSData and back is necessary to get a valid UTF-8 string.
Be aware that length will not necessarily be the length of the the NSString created in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I did this using a simple `char[]` instead of an `NSString *` for the alphabet.  I added this to a NSString category.

```
static const char __alphabet[] =
    "0123456789"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
+ (NSString *)randomString:(int)length
{
    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];
    u_int32_t alphabetLength = (u_int32_t)strlen(__alphabet);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        [randomString appendFormat:@"%c", __alphabet[arc4random_uniform(alphabetLength)]];
    }
    return randomString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method to call:**

---

```
NSString *string = [self stringWithRandomSuffixForFile:@"file.pdf" withLength:4]
```

**Method:**

---

```
- (NSString *)stringWithRandomSuffixForFile:(NSString *)file withLength:(int)length
{
    NSString *alphabet = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    NSString *fileExtension = [file pathExtension];
    NSString *fileName = [file stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@_", fileName];

    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        [randomString appendFormat:@"%C", [alphabet characterAtIndex: arc4random_uniform((int)[alphabet length]) % [alphabet length]]];
    }
    [randomString appendFormat:@".%@", fileExtension];

    NSLog(@"## randomString: %@ ##", randomString);
    return randomString;
}
```

**Results:**

---

```
## randomString: file_Msci.pdf ##
## randomString: file_xshG.pdf ##
## randomString: file_abAD.pdf ##
## randomString: file_HVwV.pdf ##
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to good answer given by Melvin, here is a function I made (**in SWIFT!**) to get a random string:

```
func randomStringOfLength(length:Int)->String{
    var wantedCharacters:NSString="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789"
    var s=NSMutableString(capacity: length)
    for (var i:Int = 0; i < length; i++) {
        let r:UInt32 = arc4random() % UInt32( wantedCharacters.length)
        let c:UniChar = wantedCharacters.characterAtIndex( Int(r) )
        s.appendFormat("%C", c)
    }
    return s
}
```

Here is a test result from calling `randomStringOfLength(10)`:   **uXa0igA8wm**

Answer (score 1):

```
static NSUInteger length = 32;
static NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
NSMutableString * randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)[letters length])]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generates lowercase alphanumeric random string with given length:

```
-(NSString*)randomStringWithLength:(NSUInteger)length
{
    NSMutableString* random = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];

    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        char c = '0' + (unichar)arc4random()%36;
        if(c > '9') c += ('a'-'9'-1);
        [random appendFormat:@"%c", c];
    }

    return random;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**for Swift 3.0**

```
func randomString(_ length: Int) -> String {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    let len = UInt32(letters.length)

    var randomString = ""

    for _ in 0 ..< length {
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(len)
        var nextChar = letters.character(at: Int(rand))
        randomString += NSString(characters: &nextChar, length: 1) as String
    }

    return randomString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ASCII_START_NUMERS 0x30
#define ASCII_END_NUMERS 0x39
#define ASCII_START_LETTERS_A 0x41
#define ASCII_END_LETTERS_Z 0x5A
#define ASCII_START_LETTERS_a 0x61
#define ASCII_END_LETTERS_z 0x5A

-(NSString *)getRandomString:(int)length {
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    while (result.length != length) {
        NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:1];
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, [data mutableBytes]);
        Byte currentChar = 0;
        [data getBytes:&currentChar length:1];
        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (currentChar > ASCII_START_NUMERS && currentChar < ASCII_END_NUMERS) { // 0 to 0
            [result appendString:s];
            continue;
        }
        if (currentChar > ASCII_START_LETTERS_A && currentChar < ASCII_END_LETTERS_Z) { // 0 to 0
            [result appendString:s];
            continue;
        }
        if (currentChar > ASCII_START_LETTERS_a && currentChar < ASCII_END_LETTERS_z) { // 0 to 0
            [result appendString:s];
            continue;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modification for keithyip's answer:

```
+ (NSString *)randomAlphanumericStringWithLength:(NSInteger)length
{
    static NSString * const letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        srand(time(NULL));
    });

    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        [randomString appendFormat:@"%C", [letters characterAtIndex:arc4random() % [letters length]]];
    }

    return randomString;
}
```