# Generate string of random characters cocoa?

Tags: string, cocoa, nsstring, character

I know how to generate random numbers, but what I really need is a string of random characters. This is what I have so far:

```
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789?%$";

    char generated;
    generated = //how do i define this?

    NSLog(@"generated =%c", generated);
    [textField setStringValue:generated];
```

Comment: Note that `char generated;` declares a variable holding *one* character, not an array of characters. Also, `setStringValue:` takes a pointer to an NSString object, not a C string.

Comment: Do you want to generate a string of any random characters, including unprintables, or only characters in the `letters` string?

Comment: Only characters in the letters string

Comment: Oh I see because a char data type holds only a single character. Yes so I got it working with NSMutableString. Thanks for the tips. Also the book you recommended is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this SO Q & A.

[Generate a random alphanumeric string in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633801/generate-a-random-alphanumeric-string-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString*)generateRandomString:(int)num {
    NSMutableString* string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        [string appendFormat:@"%C", (unichar)('a' + arc4random_uniform(25))];
    }
    return string;
}
```

then Call it like this for a 5 letter string:

```
NSString* string = [self generateRandomString:5];
```