# Objective C - Fill a UIlabel with a random string after clicking a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, random, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate a random alphanumeric string in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633801/generate-a-random-alphanumeric-string-in-cocoa)

I'm new to objective c and I would like to add the following functionality to my app:

I have a label which has default text after the app launches.
I want for that label to change to a random string each time the user clicks a button.
It does not matter if the string repeats itself eventually, as long as it is random.

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code :

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
```

for generating the random  string.

or

You can create  array that contains number of strings. Assuming you created 10 strings and put them in an array then:

```
int rand= arc4random()%10 
NSString *str=[array objectAtIndex:rand];
```

Comment: Don't use arc4random in combination with the modulo operator. What you want is: uint_32_t rand = arc4random_uniform(10);