# Generate a random alphanumeric String in ios

Tags: ios, random

How to Generate a random  non-repeated(without repeating same alphabet) alphanumeric string from a given String in ios?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2633948/1186689

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a random alphanumeric string in cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633801/generate-a-random-alphanumeric-string-in-cocoa)

Comment: how do you mean _non-repeated_? are you looking for unique string identifier in runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function will take a string and randomise it, usually each character from the input string only once:

```
- (NSString *)randomizeString:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *input = [str mutableCopy];
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];

    NSUInteger len = input.length;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        NSInteger index = arc4random_uniform((unsigned int)input.length);
        [output appendFormat:@"%C", [input characterAtIndex:index]];
        [input replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1) withString:@""];
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-(NSString *)randomStringWithLength: (int) len 

{

  NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

   NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: len];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) 
{

         [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
    }

    return randomString;
}`
```