# Objective-C: strlen returning wrong values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, security-framework

So I'm using the random string generation solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633948/2113110).

Then I'm saving the result to the keychain, except that I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`, and the `result` variable containing OSStatus is `32767`.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried running `strlen()` on both `characters` and `generatedKey` - it always returns some ridiculous numbers, as well as running simple `[characters length]`. I believe there is the problem - it should return 256.

I know this is probably silly, but I'm lost and Google does not help.

```
int len = 256;

NSString *characters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
NSMutableString *generatedKey = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: len];
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    [generatedKey appendFormat: @"%C", [characters characterAtIndex: arc4random_uniform([characters length]) % [characters length]]];
}

const char *encryptedPass = [generatedKey UTF8String];
OSStatus result = SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent(kSecGenericPasswordItemClass, &list, len, encryptedPass, someKeychain, accessRef, &someKeychainItem);
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `strlen` here. also what is the value of `[characters length]`? and you really should use `arc4random_buf` to fill buffer with random bytes

Comment: `[characters length]` returns `140735225418784`. I'll take a look at `arc4random_buf` in a minute, thanks. Anyway, problem is still here.

Comment: Why are you doing `arc4random_uniform([characters length]) % [characters length]`? The division will never change the answer you already got from `arc4random_uniform()`.

Comment: Your string creation code works as expected here. There must be a problem with the other arguments to your call to `SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent()`

Comment: You're right, there was a problem with one of the attributes in the list, thanks for pointing it out. I'm still curious how to obtain the length of the generatedKey, however.

Comment: @MichałSiwek - You find the length of an `NSMutableString` the same way as for its superclass `NSString`, and you're already doing the latter...