# Saving many pdf locally on device and retrieving it on click

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"PDFLINK"];
// Get the PDF Data from the url in a NSData Object
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString * name = @"First";
// Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];



NSString *newFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.pdf"];
NSError *error;
if ([fileManager createFileAtPath:newFilePath contents:pdfData attributes:nil])
{
    NSLog(@"Create Sucess");
    [self loadPDF];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Create error: %@", error);
}

}


-(void)loadPDF
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSArray *resultArray = [fileManager subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    if (![resultArray containsObject:arrObj])
    {
        // do something
    }
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[resultArray objectAtIndex:0]];

   // Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
   //NSLog(@"The filePath %@",filePath);
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
   NSLog(@"The url %@",url);
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [_webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [_webView setDelegate:self];
   [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Here is my code.I have more 10 pdf and want to store them locally on device and display next time without download.

It saves the pdf again and i cannot check whether it is downloaded or not ?

Please help me

Comment: down vote happens because, you didnt mention what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Thnx for letting me know.. just edited my question again

Comment: what do you mean by "it saves pdf again" ?

Comment: I meant from my code, i am saving file again and again
How to check if the file is download and open from the path it is save ?
Any idea ??

Comment: Look as `NSFileManager`. It has methods to see if a file exists or not.

Comment: Why another downvote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean but, to download a file , you need to use NSData:

```
   NSString *stringURL = @"your file URL";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.extension"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Now the downloaded file exists at filePath and you can get it by using:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename with extension"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

you can try this to check if file exists at file path:

```
 NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString* file = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file];

 if(fileExists){
         //dont download, just grab it and display it
   }
     else{
      //download and display it
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Could you help me download file if it does not exist and open the file from the path if the file is downloaded ?

Comment: Thanks .. it should help :)

Comment: NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.extension"];

Comment: any issues with that line?

Comment: NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"%@",randomString];
 I am tring to give new name each time but it says data argument cannot be use by format string

Comment: try this for generating random string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633801/generate-a-random-alphanumeric-string-in-cocoa

Comment: Also could you explain why i am getting more down vote even though i edited my question and you are helping with correct solution ?

Comment: There are millions of developers out there in SO, and your question got viewed by 26 devs..... some of them didnt consider this as valuable question, because it contains lots of code and you didnt mention exactly what is wrong with your code.Moreover there are many answers similar to your question available in SO. Even I just copied a prt of my answer from some one's answer. You get downvote because your question lack reasearch

Comment: Dont worry about the downvotes. It is quite common in here. Try to ask more qualitative questions in future which shows your effort

Comment: Thank for your help and i would like to select your answer and give it a plus point .. but my score is low :(

Thanks for all your help